# How to use environment variables in VS config?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, visual-studio-2017

I tried to use environment variable in VS configuration, but apparently it ignores them. Below I am trying to use `%CUDA_PATH%`

[image]

I know I need to restart application after environment change. I set `%CUDA_PATH%` many months ago.

Answer (score 0):

They should be named in brackets:

`$(CUDA_PATH)\include`

I didn't find explicit doc for this. Would be appreciated.